# Parse Cloud Code returns Parse Objects not allowed here

Tags: parse-platform, ionic3, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to retrieve data from the Database of Parse Server and I am facing a 500 Internal Error.

My class is "Friends" and the column is "fromUser", which is a Pointer to <_User> class.

The point is to get the usernames from the column "username" which is inside of the "User" Class.

I develop the app with Ionic 3 and trying to run the function with a current user logged in to retrieve the data.

My cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('FriendsQuery', function(req,res) {
const query = new Parse.Query("Friends");
query.equalTo("fromUser", request.params.currentuser);
query.find().then((results) => {
    res.success(results);
})
.catch(() =>  {
  response.error("user lookup failed");
});
});
```

and my typescript code

```
currentUser = Parse.User.current();
retrieveFriends(){
if (this.currentUser= Parse.User.current()) {
  const passdata = Parse.User.current();
  Parse.Cloud.run('FriendsQuery', {currentuser: this.currentUser }).then(
  res => {
    console.log(res)
    }
  )
}
```

}

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

for parse cloud code objects not allowed so you have to send only the user id and do a query in cloud to get the user object like the following

typescript code:

```
    currentUser = Parse.User.current();
retrieveFriends(){
if (this.currentUser= Parse.User.current()) {
  const passdata = Parse.User.current();
  Parse.Cloud.run('FriendsQuery', {currentuser: this.currentUser.id }).then(
  res => {
    console.log(res)
    }
  )
}
}
```

cloud code:

```
    Parse.Cloud.define('FriendsQuery', function(req,res) {
const query = new Parse.Query("Friends");
var currentId =  req.params.currentuser;
var currentuserobject = {};
 var currentuserquery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    currentuserquery.equalTo("objectId", currentId);  // find all the women
    currentuserquery.first({
      success: function(user) {
        user = currentuserobject;
      }
    });
query.equalTo("fromUser", currentuserobject);
query.find().then((results) => {
    res.success(results);
})
.catch(() =>  {
  response.error("user lookup failed");
});
});
```

Comment: Hi, Marcos and thank you. Console log returnes an empty array.I attach image. I have edited the question to be more clear. [link] (https://imgur.com/a/t7c6v)

Answer (score 0):

so please try this

```
Parse.Cloud.define('FriendsQuery', function(req,res) {
var currentId =  req.params.currentuser;
var currentuserquery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    currentuserquery.equalTo("objectId", currentId);  // find all the women
    currentuserquery.first({
      success: function(user) {
      const query = new Parse.Query("Friends");
      query.equalTo("fromUser", user);
      query.find().then((results) => {
      res.success(results);
      })

      }
    })

.catch(() =>  {
  res.error("user lookup failed");
});
});
```

Comment: Hi Marcos, it seems to work somehow, but it returnes in console log only one object not the array, which I need. Also, with "first" it returns only one result. However, with this function I am able to pass the current user id:                  retrieveFriends(){
   if (this.currentUser= Parse.User.current()) {
     console.log(this.currentUser.id)
     Parse.Cloud.run('FriendsQuery', {currentuser: this.currentUser.id}).then(
     res => {       
       console.log(res)
       });
   }
   } So I can send to the server the id of the user, but I need as response the array, not the object

Comment: this should return an array of objects unless there is only one object in the database class friends please send screenshoot of your parse dashboard

Comment: this is the dashboard.maybe my concept of query is wrong. I want to retrieve the list of friends of a user. So when i query toUser or from User, I want as result the other user. [link] (https://imgur.com/a/L3BGO)

Comment: yes it is better to add a relation column instead of pointer and this relation would contain all ids of friends

Comment: you mean to add an extra column to Users class where it could be an array of friends?with their ids?

Comment: Actually it will be relation which point to user class not array it will be easier to read and add objects to it

Comment: Thank you for your interest Marcos, but unfortunately I cant get it..I opened a new question about this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46731044/parse-cloude-right-query-to-retrieve-friendslist-and-not)