# Parse Cloud Right Query to retrieve Friendslist and not (like Instagram)

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I have the class "Users" the default of Parse Dashboad. I have also the class "Friends", where I store the friendships between users like this:
There are two columns, "toUser" and "fromUser", which are showing who of the two users sent the friend request. These two columns are Pointers(Pointer<_User>) to the Users Class.

My concept is to retrieve two lists:
1. Friendlist for the logged in user
2. Userlist of users (who are not friends with the logged in user)

What would be the appropriate queries for that?

The first one logically should not scan all the class Users because it may slow down the perfomance of the app which is using Ionic 3 and Angular 4

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you don't need another class to do so all you need is a relation column in the default user class

to add new friend you just need the following code

```
var friendtoadd 
//this is the friend object from parse user class you want to add you can get it by anyway you want
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
var relation = currentUser.relation("friends");
relation.add(friendtoadd)
currentUser.save();
```

to retrieve array of friends of logged in user you can use the following code

```
  var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
  var friendRelation = currentUser.relation('friends');  
  var env = this
  friendRelation.query().find({
    success: function(users) {
       for (var i = 0; i< users.length; i++) {
       var object = users[i];
       env.friends.push(object)
       console.log(env.friends)
        }


      } 
    });
```

// you should define   friends = []; in the class

Comment: by the way to get list of users who not friend with the current user is bad idea because he may have 0 friends and in this case you will run in a very slow query getting all users of the database

Comment: thank you Marcos, I got the point, but I need the class "Friends" because I retrieve extra info from it, like push and local notifications from who user the friend request sent.And you are right about the all users query, and i would like to to limit it only by filtering the users in the search while user types a username, like instagram does. But how..?In general i need the philosophy of instagram

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your question right you want to find the friend requests you `sent`, or the ones you `received`. because I don't see where you made a relation between the user and his friends.
this is the code if you want to do this using cloud code:

First I validated the parameters of the `friendRequest` being saved :

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Friends", function(request, response){
  var friendRequest = request.object;
  if (!friendRequest.has("toUser") || !friendRequest.has("fromUser")) {
    response.error("Invalid parameters");
    return;
  }
  response.success();
});
```

then I created two cloud functions, one for retrieving the `sentRequests`:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getSentRequests", function(request, response){
  var query = new Parse.Query("Friends");
  query.equalTo("fromUser", request.user);
  if (!request.master) {
    query.find({ sessionToken: request.user.getSessionToken() }).then(function(friends){
      response.success(friends);
    });
  }else{
    query.find({useMasterKey:true}).then(function(friends){
      response.success(friends);
    });
  }
});
```

and you can call this either from a logged in user or using the masterKey if you want, and the other query is for the `recievedRequests`:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getRecievedRequests", function(request, response){
  var query = new Parse.Query("Friends");
  query.equalTo("toUser", request.user);
  if (!request.master) {
    query.find({ sessionToken: request.user.getSessionToken() }).then(function(users){
      response.success(users);
    });
  }else{
    query.find({useMasterKey:true}).then(function(users){
      response.success(users);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Abubakr. I attach image to be more crystal. The table-class "Friends" has stored the friends. Who sent the request and who received it. As logged in user i want to retrieve my friends [link](https://imgur.com/a/XWWT8)

Comment: Sorry I am not fimiliar with ionic 3 and angular 4, but with  a little research I found that you can call the function name and intercept the results using providers, I don't fully understand how, post an answer if you find the right code for it.

Comment: I know how to call the cloud function but before that I should define the structure of the database or the concept for the query to retrieve what I want

Comment: When you call the `getSentRequests` function it will return the first object in the image you attached above, and when you call `getReceivedRequests` function it will return the 3 below objects in the image, because the only constraint you can have here is the current parse user object by using request.user in cloud code it will return the currently logged in user, then you can display the results you want from the objects you received.